# Incomplete User Input Histogram C

Tags: c, histogram

Got an incomplete histogram that needs to be completed for a project.

```
   #include <stdio.h>



/**
    * Prints a histogram to the screen using horizontal bar chart.
    * Parameters:
    *   list - a list of integers
    *   n - the number of values in the list
    */
    void printHistogram ( int *hist, int n );

   /**
 * This program requests data from the user and then
 * computes and prints a histogram. You may assume that
     * the data values entered are in the range of 0 to 9.
    */
   int main ( void )
   {


int i, n;


// Data entry
//
printf ("How many values in your data set? ");
scanf ("%d", &n);

int list[n];
for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
    printf ("Enter a value: ");
    scanf ("%d", &list[i]);
}

// Processing data to compute histogram

int hist[10];    


// Printing histogram
printHistogram ( hist, 10);

return 0;
}



void printHistogram ( int *list, int n )
{
int i, j;

for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
    printf ("[%d] ", i);
    for (j = 0; j < list[i]; j++)
        printf ("*");
    printf ("\n");
  }
 }
```

Comment: OK. Good luck with that

Comment: _Processing data to compute histogram_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide too little info for an actual solution but anyway.
So, I assume that you want to print a histogram with the number of occurrences of an integer from 1-9(At least, this is what I understood).
A possible way to do that is to create an ingeter array that will keep the number of occurrences of every integer. It will obviously have 10 items. When you get to the input, for every integer that you come across, you will incrememt the according item in the array. Note that you do not need to search in the array for every integer. 
If you want to count the occurrences of words-strings, this is something a little more complicated because it requires the use of a struct, but it is based in the same idea.